# Cross-Validation model selection

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have done 10-Fold CV on my data and I have selected my model complexity from the result. Now for my best complexity, I will be having 10 different models. Should I take the average of these models for my testing or should I just fit a model of our selected complexity on our CV data and then test?

Comment: CV is a model selection method and not a model creation technique. So having selected your model complexity now you have to create a single model on the entire dataset then use that model to predict on any new-test data.

Answer (score 0):

You re-train the model based on your best complexity (or parameters) on the complete training data. Then you can test the model on un-touched test dataset and report your error measure.

Comment: Whats wrong with taking the average of those models?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with taking average. It would be a sort of ensembling. Then you are trying to solve another task. You find a parameter for your ensemble and not a single model. But remember that this is prone to overfitting. You are selecting parameters in your outer loop, such that it minimizes the ensemble error on the training data. If you optimize several parameters, you may have a "lucky" fold that minimizes the error and there would be no other chance to train it on a set different from what it is optimized on.

Comment: The idea in CV is to select parameters in a scenario different from final model training.

Comment: Ok, let's say we have 5 fold and from the result, I chose the model of complexity x. Now for model complexity x, I have 5 models and if I ensemble how is overfitting possible? Because in each of 5 validation sets are from different splits and each model of complexity has seen different data and averaging them should also give a good fit for the whole data.

Comment: You should look at computing cv-error as a random process and the cv-error is a random variable. Assume you observe a lucky fold that minimizes the cv-error.  If you use the ensemble of the same 5 models found in cv, you would be prone to overfitting. However If you fix that parameters and re-train your 5 ensemble based on a different random split, then you are not.